# How can I prevent submitting a textfield when hitting the "Go" button on iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone

I'm using jquery.quicksearch on my page: http://barkeeper.thomaskile.me/?side=sok - an a couple of others..
And I've managed to prevent *submitting* the form if the user hits the enter-key on their keyboard with this code:

```
$('form>input[type="text"].quicksearch').keypress(function(e){  if(e.which==13 ){return false;}  });
```

But on my iPhone there's a "Go" button. And when I hit that, the form gets submitted.

What I would like it to do, is to just close the keypad. Just like when I hit the "finnish" button.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm guessing the same goes for Androide phones aswell..

**EDIT:**
This code might prevent the "Go"-button aswell? Just tried a couple of times..
Bus still, is there a way to close the keypad when hitting the "Go" button?

Comment: perhaps, how do you want the form to be submitted with?

Comment: It should not be submitted at all. It's just a textfield, and it's only for filtering down a list that is already presented on the page..

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the form from submitting by any means you should intercept the `submit()` event:

```
$("form.quicksearch").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```